# Decrypting Browser Cookies

Tags: cookies, decryption, backdoor, mimikatz

So I am trying to write my own backdoor with python and it is something like Metaploit, where you can run a single command and it would do the work for you, so I am trying to implement a cookie decoder/decrypter, so I started doing it on my own Host machine and I decided to start with Microsoft Edge, the path the Microsoft Edge stores the cookies is ***C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies*** or at least that is what google says, and obviously when you open that file you are going to see unreadable text.

I tried researching for ways to decrypt it, I asked gpt4, gpt3.5, looked in stackoverflow, looked in reddit nothing helped, all the scripts that I found were for chrome (even the ones for chrome are not getting chrome's cookies properly).

I recently watched John Hammond's YouTube video *(He tried to hack me...)* where he was analyzing a malware, and I saw that the one that he was analyzing was going into some specific directories for wallets, browsers etc., possibly extracting the cookies and trying to send it to the attacker, that means that it is not impossible to decrypt cookies.

I actually do remember on the top of my head the someone told me that mimikatz (kiwi) would help with this kind of stuff, but I did not find anything useful.

And even though mimikatz could help it would be quite dangerous if I embed mimikatz into my backdoor since mimikatz is easily detectable by almost every AV. But for a starting point if mimikatz would help I would appreciate it.

**So my question is how can I decrypt browser Cookies into JSON format that would be accepted by the "Cookie-Editor" extension.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited my question, please check it now

Comment: Have you done any recon on what the Cookies file actually is? 

maybe you should try and figure out first what the file is... like using the `file` command on a Linux (wsl ftw). I suspect (with reason) its a type of datastore.

Comment: also are you aware of this gist? https://gist.github.com/creachadair/937179894a24571ce9860e2475a2d2ec

it should help with understanding whats going on.

Comment: Well they are SQLite as you can see in here:
`┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt]
└─# file Cookies 
Cookies: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3041002, file counter 53554, database pages 332, 1st free page 323, free pages 8, cookie 0x1b, schema 4, UTF-8, version-valid-for 53554`

Comment: And for the gist, I tried connnecting to the Cookies using sqlite3 and tried to extract th host, name and the value however for some reason it does not output anything for the value:
`┌──(root㉿kali)-[/opt]
└─# sqlite3 Cookies
SQLite version 3.42.0 2023-05-16 12:36:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT host_key, name, value FROM cookies;
.bing.com|_EDGE_V|
.bing.com|SRCHD|
.bing.com|SRCHUID|
ntp.msn.com|sptmarket|
.msn.com|_EDGE_V|
.msn.com|_SS|
.youtube.com|LOGIN_INFO|
.bing.com|MMCASM|
.kooora.com|cognativexpixel|
`
@LvB

Comment: you can find the methods in Chromium's source code since it's open source.  Be aware that you have to run your code on the same machine that the cookies are stored.  (at least in Windows because DPAPI is used to encrypt/decrypt)  I believe in Linux the key is "peanuts" or something silly like that.

Comment: is not there an already written tool like laZagne that would do that, I am not really good at reverse engineering :)

Comment: I've seen full code for it posted here at stackexchange methinks... just do a search.   If you're just trying to look at your cookie values, you can do that in the browser, though.